# Move files with robocopy instead of copy

Tags: robocopy

```
robocopy B:\Foo\ D:\890001 /MIR /COPY:DT /FFT
```

Am using the above to copy files from A to B, however I wish to move the file not copy. How can this be done without its function being compromised?

Answer (score 2):

Use `/mov`, as shown in the [documentation](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc733145.aspx).

Comment: replace /COPY:DT with /MOV?

Comment: You don't need /MIR, either.  You just need 'robocopy z:\foo y:\bar /mov'.